# How to join a 3 dimensional array into a normal array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a 3D array with lists in lists but i want each seperate list to become just one value in the list.

eg.

```
[['q', 'w', 'e'], ['w', 'e', 'r'], ['e', 'r', 't'], ['r', 't', 'y']]
```

is my 3D array with lists in lists and i want to convert this list into:

```
[qwe, wer, ert, rty]
```

effectively joining up the lists into 1 element in the list.

Is there a **simple** way to do this?

Comment: That's not a 3d array, but a 2d list.

Comment: What's the value of that `qwe` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
>>> [['q', 'w', 'e'], ['w', 'e', 'r'], ['e', 'r', 't'], ['r', 't', 'y']]
>>> [''.join(l) for l in _]
```

Output:

> ['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty']

Comment: That is not the output, but the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can `join` these together with `''.join`, and we can define a *mapping* over it:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, data))
['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty']
```